# Having Issue Importing scapy.all in my file

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, network-programming, scapy

I am having issues when importing scapy in my Ubuntu virtual machine.
I can easily use `from scapy.all import *` in the terminal.
I am using Visual Studio Code and when I hover over scapy, right click and go to defintion, it takes me to the scapy file.
Here's what solutions I've seen and tried:

1. My filename(or any filename in the folder) is not "scapy.py".
2. I've installed scapy directly from the website, used "sudo apt-get install python3-scapy" and also tried with "pip install scapy". None of which changed anything.
3. If I run another python file (without "sudo" and with "from scapy.all import *") it runs fine. But there is an import issue when I use "sudo". [image]
4. I tried to do the following to solve my issue:

   - Type in the terminal:
     `sudo mkdir /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy`
     `cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`
     `cp -avr scapy/* /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy`\

   This also didnt work out.
5. I also thought maybe I messed up some of the module files. So I tried doing everything on a new VirtualBox image. But that also failed.
6. I can type "scapy" in the terminal and it opens up fine.

my python version is 3.8.10
Scapy version: 2.4.5

I've been stuck on this for 4 days. Please help.

Comment: what is your default python version? can you run ```python --version``` and check what is the version?

Comment: it's not recommended to use sudo while working with python, you should use virtualenv instead.

Comment: I am working on an assignment and had to run everything through a makefile. So, I don't have much control over running the files. Anyways, Installing scapy to root user solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it's recommended to use **virtualenv**, it will resolve the conflict if you have multiple python versions.

- create a virtual environment,  by the following commands

  `virtualenv env -p python3`
- then activate it

  `source env/bin/activate`
- then install scapy using pip:

  `pip install scapy`

and try to import the library from there.

Answer (score 0):

Packages installed on a non-root user are not installed system wide, thus there is an import issue when you run the script as a root user
Some solutions that can be used:

1. Install **scapy** to **root** user too

- Switch to root

```
sudo su
```

- Install scapy

```
pip install scapy
```

- You can then run your script locally and no issues brought up

```
sudo python3 script.py
```

2. Alternatively, create a [virtual environment](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/)(**recommended**) and install scapy there

- Create a virtual environment

```
demo@stack:~/demo$ virtualenv venv
```

- Activate the virtual environment

```
demo@stack:~/demo$ source venv/bin/activate
```

- Install scapy via pip into the new virtual environment

```
(venv) demo@stack:~/demo$ pip install scapy
```

- You can now run your script with superuser permissions without issue

```
(venv) demo@stack:~/demo$ sudo python3 script.py
```

Comment: you are right expect the last line, you shouldn't use ```sudo``` at all, so if you are using virtualenv,  use ```python script.py ``` , using sudo will use the system root python not the one in the virtualenv.